# Necessity of keys and queries in a decoder-only transformer model

Tags: neural-networks, transformers, attention

when we compute self-attention in a decoder model, we compute, for an embedding $x$, the tensors $Q = W_Q x, K = W_K x, V = W_V x$.

However, in the next step, we compute a dot product on the embedding dimension:
$(Q|K) = x^T W_Q^T W_K x$.

In this way, the matrices $W_Q, W_K$ only appear through the product $W_Q^T W_K$. So why do we need to train two matrices if all that matters is this product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question! There are performance tricks during inference that are enabled by keeping these separate. For example, caching the $K$ tensor.

We normally would compute the product $QK$ with the whole input sequence; however, when generating a sequence at step $T$, we always have the same $T-1$ tokens, thus recomputing the whole product would be quite wasteful! We can cache the first ($T-1) \times (T-1$) submatrix in $QK$, and also cache the key embeddings (the first $T-1$ embeddings in $K$)! So each subsequent generation only needs to compute $W_Q x_T$ instead of generating the whole set of key, query embeddings.

If we only keep track of the combined product $W_QW_K$, we wouldn't be able to do this step, which reduces the complexity by a whole factor of the sequence length.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is wrong.

The described optimization trick using caching really only works **for the first** attention layer. At step $T$ you have the same $T-1$ tokens, but after the first attention layer the output embeddings **for all tokens** will be different, so you have to re-compute everything from there on. No caching is possible for the deeper attention layers.

There is actually a different reason for separating these two matrices. As OP remarked the matrices $W_Q$ and $W_K$ are only ever used in order to compute the attention scores: $x^TW_Q^TW_Kx$. You could easily use a single matrix $W_{QK} = W_Q^TW_K$ and compute the attention scores as $x^TW_{QK}x$.

Since the token embeddings have dimension $d_{model}$, the matrix $W_{QK}$ will have dimension $d_{model} \times d_{model}$.

In the multi-head attention layer your queries and keys are mapped to a $d_k$-dimensional space, where $d_k = d_{model} // n$. Now, the $W_Q$ and $W_K$ matrices have dimension $d_{model} \times d_{k}$, greatly reducing the number of trainable parameters of the model. Effectively we force the matrix $W_{QK}$ to be not just any matrix, but a matrix with rank $d_k$.

You might think that reducing the number of parameters would reduce the performance of the model, but having a full rank $W_{QK}$ matrix would indirectly result in the query and key embeddings having the same dimension $d_{model}$. However, as already mentioned, queries and keys are only ever used to compute the attention score (a single number). The smaller $d_k$-dimensional space could easily do the job, and it would prevent the model from overfitting.